# GCC debugger stack trace displays wrong file name and line number

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I am trying to port a fairly large C++ project to using g++ 4.0 on Mac OS X. My project compiles without errors, but I can't get GDB to work properly. When I look at the stack by typing "bt" on the GDB command line, all file names and line numbers displayed are wrong.

For example, according to the GDB stack trace, my `main()` function is supposed to be in stdexcept from the Mac OS X SDK, which does not make any sense.

What could cause GDB to malfunction so badly? I've already checked for #line and #file statements in my code and made sure that the code only has unix line endings. I've also cleaned and rebuilt the project. I've also tried debugging a Hello World project and that one did not have the same problem.

Could the problem have to do with one of the third party libraries I am linking and the way those are compiled? Or is it something completely different?

Here are two exemplary calls to `gcc` and `ld` as executed by [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). AFAIK all cpp-files in my project are compiled and linked with the same parameters.

> /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -x c++
>   -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -fpermissive -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -DNO_BASS_SOUND -D_DEBUG -DXCODE -D__WXMAC__ -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
>   -mfix-and-continue -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -gdwarf-2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXDEBUG__ -D__WXMAC__ -c "/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/TSDLGameBase.cpp" -o
>   "/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/build/Gemsweeper
>   Mac.build/Debug/Gemsweeper
>   Mac.build/Objects-normal/i386/TSDLGameBase.o"
>
> /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.0 -arch i386
>   -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
>   "-L/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/build/Debug"
>   -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/local/lib
>   -L/opt/local/lib "-F/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/build/Debug"
>   -F/Users/adriangrigore/Library/Frameworks
>   -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/Library/Frameworks
>   -filelist "/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/build/Gemsweeper
>   Mac.build/Debug/Gemsweeper
>   Mac.build/Objects-normal/i386/Gemsweeper
>   Mac.LinkFileList"
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 /opt/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a
>   /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a
>   /opt/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.a
>   /opt/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.a
>   /opt/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a
>   "/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/3rd
>   party/FreeImage/Dist/libfreeimage.a"
>   "/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/3rd
>   party/cpuinfo-1.0/libcpuinfo.a"
>   -L/usr/local/lib -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework System -framework QuickTime -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -lwx_macd_richtext-2.8 -lwx_macd_aui-2.8 -lwx_macd_xrc-2.8 -lwx_macd_qa-2.8 -lwx_macd_html-2.8 -lwx_macd_adv-2.8 -lwx_macd_core-2.8 -lwx_base_carbond_xml-2.8 -lwx_base_carbond_net-2.8 -lwx_base_carbond-2.8 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o "/Users/adriangrigore/Documents/Gemsweeper
>   Mac/build/Debug/Gemsweeper
>   Mac.app/Contents/MacOS/Gemsweeper Mac"

Please note that I have already asked a similar question regarding the Xcode debugger [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582412/xcode-debugger-code-window-does-not-match-stack-window), but I am reposting since I just learned that this is in fact not Xcode's fault, but a problem with GCC / ld / GDB.

**Edit:** My project makes use of the following third-party libraries: [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer), [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries), [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets). I am not sure if this matters for this problem, but I just wanted to mention it just in case it does.

I've tried compiling an Xcode SDL project template and did not experience the same problem, so it must be due to something special in my project.

**Second Edit**: As I just found out, I made a mistake while searching files with the string "This is an automatically generated". I just found several dozen files with the same string, all belonging to [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), one of the third party libraries I am using. So, the problem seems to be related to FreeImage, but I am not still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: gdb doesn't output some warning when starting?

Comment: I'm beginning to think you have a bug, pointer based, that may overwrite something...

Comment: gdb does not give any warnings when starting.

Comment: Also, I do not think that stack corruption is the problem. when running my app and setting a breakpoint with "b main", gdb already shows me a wrong a filename and line number: (gdb) b main Breakpoint 1 at 0x2af855: file /.../TWxInvalidRegCodeForm.h, line 75. That's before I even run my application.

Comment: curious here...solved it yet?

Comment: Not really. Still having the same problem. I asked in the FreeImage forums about the main function that replaced my own, but no reply so far.

Answer (score 4):

I got those symptoms, when my gdb version didn't match my g++ version.

Try to get the newest gdb.

Answer (score 1):

Your cpp files certainly have debug symbols in them (the `-gdwarf-2` option).

Do you use a separate dSYM file for the debug symbols? Or are they inside the object files. I would first try to use DWARF in dSYM files and see if that helps (or vice versa)

The third party libraries appear to be release builds though (unless you renamed them yourself of course) e.g. I know for sure boost uses the `-d` monniker in the library names to denote debug libraries (e.g. `libboost_filesystem-mt-d.a`).

Now, this shouldn't really pose a problem, it should just mean you can't step into the calls made to third party libraries. (at least not make any sense of it when you do ;) But since you have problems, it might be worth a try to link with debug versions of those libraries...

Comment: I've tried recompiling with "stabs", "dwarf" and "dwarf-with-dsym" (those are the three options that XCode offers me as debug info format), but none helped. I only noticed that, when using stabs, the location of main was supposed to be a in a different file, but it was still completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling with optimization on?  I've found that O2 or higher messes with the symbols quite a bit, making gdb and core files pretty much useless.

Also, be sure you are compiling with the -g option.

Comment: I'm tried the -gdwarf-2 option for compiling the project as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

For a test, you could check if addr2line gives you expected values.  If so, this would indicate that there's nothing wrong with the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) generated by your compile/link parameters and casts all suspicion on GDB.  If not, then suspicion is still on both the tools and the ELF file.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how do I find a suitable function address for trying this?

Comment: I tend to work on embedded platforms where it's easy to tell from the mapfile, but I suggest feeding it the address it stops at when you connect in gdb (that's shown to be in stdexcept) and see if addr2line puts that address in main().

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you are using SDL? SDL redefines `main` so your main will be named `SDL_main` and that the SDL parts might be heavy optimized so down there you'll have problem getting good gdb output.

...just a thought

[Read this](http://www.libsdl.org/faq.php?action=listentries&category=7#55)

Comment: Yes, I am using SDL. I am aware about SDL_main, but I have tried compiling a standard SDL XCode project template and the debugger worked fine. It's just in my "real" project that the debugger does not work. Also, I have turned off optimization, so I do not think that it has to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried compiling an XCode SDL
>   project template and did not
>   experience the same problem, so it
>   must be due to something special in my
>   project.

Correct. Your project settings are the thing that is different.

You will need to disable the debug optimizations in the Xcode project settings for the debug build. Xcode unfortunately makes GDB jump to weird lines (out of order) when you would expect it to move sequentially.

Go to your project settings. Set the following

```
1) Instruction Scheduling   = None
2) Optimization Level       = None [-O0]
3) ZERO_LINK                = None
```

Your problems should go after after doing this.
Here is the project settings screen that you need to change the settings on:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Optimization was already turned off, but I tried turning off Zero Link and Instruction Scheduling. Unfortunately none of this seems to make any difference. The problem still stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

From your flags the debug information should be in the object files.

Does your project settings build the executable in one location then move the final executable to another location when completed? If this is the case then gdb may not be finding the objectects files and thus not correctly retrieving the debug information from the object files.

Just a guess.

Comment: I'm not aware of something like this. Also, if this was the cause of the problem, it would also cause the problem to appear in the vanilla SDL XCode template project my real project is based on.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this several years ago when transitioning from the Codewarrior compilers to Xcode. I believe the way to get around this is to put the flag "`-fno-inline-functions`" in Other C Flags (for Dev only).

This problem was more pronounced on the PowerPC architecture for us.

**What about if you remove the "-fvisibility-inlines-hidden" and  "-mfix-and-continue" flags?**

I've never had the "fix and continue" feature work properly for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, but unfortunately adding the flag did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

WxWidgets do also define their own `main` if you use their `IMPLEMENT_APP()` macro

From [here](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm)

> As in all programs there must be a "main" function. Under wxWidgets main is implemented using this macro, which creates an application instance and starts the program.
>
> `IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)`

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614492/how-do-i-find-my-programs-main-function/618455#618455)

I have now downloaded and compiled the FreeImage sources and yes, the file `b44ExpLogTable.cpp` is compiled into `libfreeimage.a`. The problem looks like the script `gensrclist.sh` just collects all `.cpp` files without skipping the one with a main in. That script generates a file named `Makefile.srcs` but one is already supplied. (running it on my Leopard failed, some problem with `sh` - it worked if I changed `sh` to `bash`)

Before you have changed anything this gives an `a.out`

```
c++ libfreeimage.a
```

The file `Makefile.srcs` has already been created so you should be able to remove the file `b44ExpLogTable.cpp` from it. Then do

```
make -f Makefile.osx clean
make -f Makefile.osx
```

When this is done the above `c++ libfreeimage.a` should give the following error

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a new thing you can try.

Just before your own `main` you can write

```
#ifdef main
#  error main is defined
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

this should give an error if you have some header that redefines `main`.

If you define an own you might get an warning where a previous definition was made

```
#define main foo

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

You can also try to `undef` just before your `main`

```
#undef main

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```