# gdb, C++, codelite: wrong line numbers while debugging shared lib

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, codelite

My issue is similar to this:
[GCC debugger stack trace displays wrong file name and line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594782/gcc-debugger-stack-trace-displays-wrong-file-name-and-line-number)

More precisely:

- I'm using codelite 14
- gdb (Ubuntu 8.2-0ubuntu1~16.04.1) 8.2
- gcc (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010 (older version to stay compatible with my company)

I can debug the executable without any problems, but when I jump into code *inside* libraries, then:

- the correct file is opened/shown.
- but the debugger halts at the
  wrong line number when I step into (F11) the operator>> function.

This wrong line number also shows up in the call stack, eg:

```
Function        File    Line    Address
operator>>       OK     1003    0x00007ffff79867b2
inside main exe: all is fine.
```

The actual `operator>>()` starts at line 1037.
Codelite generates mk files. For the .so file it has:

```
AR       := ar rcus
CXX      := g++
CC       := gcc
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -g -gstabs -O0 -fPIC $(Preprocessors)
CFLAGS   := -Wall -g -fPIC $(Preprocessors)
ASFLAGS  := 
AS       := as
```

Based on the link above I added -gstabs, but this makes no difference.
Based on following link, I changed -O0 into -Og
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html
but the result is similar: wrong line numbers.

I built the .so file on the command line like this:

```
make clean -f filename.mk
make -f filename.mk
```

I had to tell codelite/gdb where the source code is for the so-file.
Right click on the project, Settings, Debugger and here you can fill in the directory with the source code of the so-file.
With this in place, gdb jumps at least to the right file.

But it would be enormously helpful if I can debug inside the .so and have correct line numbers. Now F10/F11 jumps around in the correct file (until the signal SIGABRT), but at wrong lines. Because of that, I can't pinpoint the cause. Also, a breakpoint I placed at the start of `operator>>` is ignored. I'm out of ideas. I assume -O9 disables whole program optimization.

BTW, before debugging I rebuild all, so I am sure I don't run any code while the source files are newer.

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of the source? If so, are you sure you've pointed to the right copy, and are using the `.so` that you intended to use?  Also, `-gstabs` is ancient and should _never_ be used on any Linux system.

Comment: Hi, there are no multiple copies of the source. With obdump I can see the file and path as explained here (DW_AT_comp_dir and DW_AT_name are correct, except for that the name contains the full path.

https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/gdb-source-path/

My workaround for now is this:
The so was made by my company and consists of only one header (that was already included in my project) and one cpp file. I added this as existing file to my project and removed the so from the libs. Now I can debug into this library.
And: the code I was working on works now..

Thanks for your help